# make a loop for a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, file-get-contents

lets say i have an array of urls
and i need to make file get contents for each item on array
how can i do it ??

```
$url = "http://seetelkol.com/forum/forum-46/";

$subject=  file_get_contents($url);
$subject=   preg_match_all('%<a class="title" href="http://seetelkol.com/forum/thread-(.*?)/" id="thread_title_(.*?)>%', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
$patterns = implode('|', $result);

$patterns = preg_match_all('%http://seetelkol.com/forum/thread-[0-9]{0,9}/%', $patterns, $new, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($new);
```

can any one tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

- First off, it is not necessary to use 2 preg_match_all
- In the    regular expression, you need to escape literal characters **\.**
- Finally, you must use the flag "**s**"

Try

```
<?php 

  $url  = 'http://seetelkol.com/forum/forum-46/';
  $subject = file_get_contents($url);

  preg_match_all('#<a class="title" href="http:\/\/seetelkol\.com/forum/thread\-([0-9]+)\/" id="thread_title_(?:[0-9]+)">#s', $subject, $result);

  print_r($result); 


 ?>
```

Comment: ok i understand that
but 
in my examle i get the urls only 
and what i need is 
make file_GET_CONTENTS foreach url of theme like loop